# What is the use of .qmg file in android?

Tags: android

can anyone help me out for this?

whats the use of .qmg file for Bootanimation.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

QMG files are created by Samsung Theme Designer application. You can follow the instruction to create and port zip into QMG [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/how-to-create-qmg-boot-animations-t2217795).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's used for the boot animation...

Comment: Thanks Falmarri.. But I need to know whether it can differ from device to device.. if yes then then on what basis this .qmg file selected or created ..

Comment: It's based on the firmware. What's the point of your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to change the Bootanimation. Is .qmg file effects bootanimation?

Comment: It's firmware defined how it displays the boot animation. And you'll definitely need a rooted devices to do that. I have no idea what format the .qmg file is in, or if it's the same across all firmware versions. You'll have to tell us what firmware you're using to even get any kind of answer.

Comment: Thanks Falmarri. I got the answer for that. And what i got to know is Qmg file is an animated format for the PNG and its used in bootanimation. I used a software and converted png files into a single QMG. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Pintu, do you get me the software download link which converts .png file to .qmg file

Answer (score 0):

Qmg files are the outdated boot animation system that Samsung uses.  Most websites only provide zip files which don't work on Samsung devices.  If you want to install zip files on Samsung phones you have to install a custom ROM.